# Create master volume control keyboard macro in linux.

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a keyboard with no specially designed keys, so I was thinking I'd put in windows+up/down for controlling the master volume.

How would I do this?

Comment: I actually found this really easysolution. http://techhamlet.com/2011/12/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux/

Comment: You didn't specify a linux up front, some have that built in.  If you decide you need a more advanced distro at some point, xbindkeys has a gui too.  I just don't use those much.  Glad you're squared away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is installing [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html).

To set it up, once installed you need to set the `~/.xbindkeysrc` file to tell it your commands.  (You can copy over their defaults, but in my opinion they are awful - one example being <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does not FIND anymore. If you want the defaults, just type xbindkeys and it will instruct you how to get them).

So instead, I would suggest you make your own with vim or gedit or whatever you prefer with the layout of:

```
vim ~/.xbindkeysrc

"command to run"
(tab) keycommand
```

(the tab is a real tab, not the word+perens "(tab)")

To get the key code, run (in the terminal) `$ xbindkeys -k`, that will pop up a dialog to tell you it's ready, hit your key codes and it will spit out the "command to run" (if it is bound to anyting) and then the keys (like <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>). That will be all the info needed for you to set up `.xbindkeysrc`.

For example, here is how mine looks (picture the non quoted lines as tabbed in):

```
"amixer set Master 5%+"
XF86AudioRaiseVolume
"amixer set Master 5%-"
XF86AudioLowerVolume
"amixer set Master toggle"
XF86AudioMute
"gnome-screensaver-command -l"
XF86ScreenSaver
"banshee --next"
XF86AudioNext
"banshee --restart-or-prev"
XF86AudioPrev
"banshee --toggle-playing"
XF86AudioPlay
"action"
XF86Launch1
```

Last thing you need to do is set xbindkeys to run at login.  For Gnome/Mate/Cinnamon hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type gnome-session-properties, click Add+ and for the command it's xbindkeys.  The other two items are up to whatever you want.

Comment: I do like your answer. It's good an informative.